# What server should I use if I am expecting over 20k visits/day?

Tags: web

I recently launched a fantasy football online game for the English premier league called Myfpl11.com and I want to know what server should I choose if I am expecting 20k visits a day. My visits are going up and I want the site to keep performing smoothly. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the wrong area of StackExchange to ask this sort of question. However ...

The first thing you should do is get prepared to scale horizontally instead of vertically. If you keep growing you will soon grow out of any single server that you purchase.

Instead, what you need to do is start looking at ways to modify your website to be able to work over multiple systems. If you're experiencing load issues on the server you currently have, spin up another one of the exact same instance and move the database to that server, so you will then have two -- one dedicated to the database (which will really help it do its job) and one dedicated to serving traffic.

From there look at how you can scale in to multiple web processes, databases and add caching layers.

You can add cloudflare.com as your DNS service which will help you out by better caching your assets, but most importantly they will deliver a technical issues page to your users if your site does fall over at any stage. This is really helpful for saving face, because they will get an actual page with a message instead of a continually loading white-page.

Look at using services like digitalocean.com or linode.com (both very affordable and great staff) where you can easily add/remove resources as you need them.